# android viewPager2 turns on offscreenPageLimit

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager2, off-screen

android viewPager2 turns on offscreenPageLimit, manually slide to switch Fragments. Fragments will not call back the life cycle, but clicking the TabView in the bound TabLayout will call back the life cycle.

I expect to be able to call back the life cycle in any switching behavior.
I need to process data in onResume life cycle.

Comment: when i set smoothScroll = false，i found if I don't use Debug, dipatchStateChanged     not executed